# How to relocate face points in opencv / face distortion

Tags: animation, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

I have to simulate facial expressions on a face image ( say open mouth ). For this I first extracted the facial feature points and found the corners of the lips. Now I need to deform the image by moving the points down.

[image]

In the above image I need to move the points ( 2 ) and ( 3 ) to some distance left and right respectively. And point ( 18 ) and ( 19 ) littele bit down. So that I will get an expression like opened mouth.

**My Questions:**

1) Is this the above way right to proceed to simulate facial expression?

**2) If it is right how to move the points and create a new image in opencv?**

Comment: What about taking shots of each expression and showing that when desired? And do morphing for in between animation? (No, OpenCV isn't the tool for that.)

Comment: ah, nice. what did you use to get the points ?

Comment: @berak This is a sample image of STASM.

Comment: @SamuelAudet The input for this project will be only neutral frontal face.

Comment: i've seen a lot of people using delauny triangulation from those points, and then texture warping or distortion in opengl or even opencv.  https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter7_HeadPoseEstimation  looks quite related, parts of the "MasteringOpencv" book are on google.books

Comment: @berak Thanks for the info..It would be good if you post it as an answer with little more details.

Comment: @berak It would be good if you guide me with some examples on how to disort an image with given points. That is where i got stucked.

Comment: @2vision2 did you get any breakthrough for this particular problem ?

Comment: @2vision2 Have you got the solution?? Please help me out i'm on the same stage.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly recent survey and course of techniques people have used in this area is here:
http://old.siggraph.org/publications/2006cn/course30.pdf

TL:DR. There is no "right" way to do it, in any absolute sense. You need to define your goal in a way that is computable. Then figure out what additional (prior) information you need to reach it, in addition to the image data themselves. Fiddling with "texture warping" or other interpolation schemes before you decide what you need to do is a waste of time.

You mention "an expression like an opened mouth", and I interpret that to mean that you'd like to produce an image similar to what the real face would look like if the subject had been photographed with their mouth open. The markers you found obviously do not give enough information about that - in particular, they do not express any notion of "mouth". In fact, that notion is nowhere to be found in the image. So, strictly speaking, your task is unsolvable unless you throw more information into it.

I suggest you take a look at the paper pointed above, and rethink your problem again.

Comment: Can you comment on some appps like <http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TgR-qWIEYKY>, <http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXDrbmbg7Ps> -- just the talking part...

Comment: They both appear to be renderings of an animated 3d model. The "talking" is probably done by animating with shapes indexed via some kind of speech processing. It is not necessary to have a fully working speech recognition to produce a plausible animation - the timing of lips opening-closing matters more than anything else, as most people are not capable of lip-reading, but can tell when the timing is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... ** My Question Again :: ** I have a neutral face and the facial landmarks wherever necessary (marking can be done manually) ... How can I open a closed mouth .. More cases ..move eyebrows ... Open by how much isn't my question... how to open... Can you kindly comment on the above

Comment: Also quality ( animated face need not be exactly like when a real person opens a mouth) isn't my concern... I just want to start with basic animations on a face like open a mouth, open mouth widely, .. slightly move eybrows. @ Franco Callari :: Your comments will be very helpful..

Comment: Have you actually read the paper I pointed above. From there, for example, take a look at http://mrl.nyu.edu/~bregler/videorewrite/

Answer (score 0):

so, here we go again..

i've seen a lot of people using delauny triangulation from those points, and then texture warping or distortion in opengl or even opencv.

https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter7_HeadPoseEstimation

looks quite related, parts of the "MasteringOpencv" book are on google.books